# Instance of any class as input of a method in java

Tags: java, class, methods

```
public class Class{
   public void method(class a, class b){
      //some stuff
   }
}
```

What i want is that `a` and `b` can be instances of any class. Is this legal in java? Is there any way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the compiler complain? If not, it is legal.

Comment: what about `public void method(Object a, Object b){}`

Comment: Do you want to pass *classes* or *instances*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Object. Any class in Java is a (direct or indirect) sub-class of Object.

```
public class MyClass {
   public void method(Object a, Object b){
      //some stuff
   }
}
```

Oh, and don't use the class name "Class". It's already used in Java.

Comment: @NabeelOmer I meant the upper case `Class` - you shouldn't create a class of that name (as it might hide `java.lang.Class`).

Comment: The class that i am expecting will be a child class of `JFrame` and I will have to call that class's methods. But objects don't allow that. How do i do that?

Comment: @NabeelOmer If you only expect sub-classes of JFrame, it would make more sense for the method to have parameters of type JFrame, which would allow you to call JFrame methods. If your method also handles non JFrame parameters, you'll have to check the type and cast to JFrame - `if (a instanceof JFrame) {JFrame j = (JFrame)a; j.someJFrameMetohd...}`

Comment: I changed the parameters to type `JFrame` and its done.

Answer (score 5):

Your given code is not legal because `class` is a keyword in java see [JLS 3.9. Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9)

USe can use `Object` class from [JLS 4.3.2. The Class Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.2)

> The class Object is a superclass (§8.1.4) of all other classes.

Use following:

```
public class Class{
   public void method(Object a, Object b){
      //some stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using generics:

```
public class Class{
   public <T1, T2> void method(T1 a, T2 b){
      //some stuff
   }
}
```

If you'd ever need to return something with type connected to argument types, you'd be able to, like this:

```
public class Class{
   public <T1, T2> Map<T1, T2> toMap(T1 key, T2 val){
      Map<T1, T2> out = new HashMap<>();
      out.put(key, value);
      return out;
   }
}
```

Comment: Its a nice idea but my teacher would not allow it, we haven't formally dealt with generics yet, its later in the syllabus though.

Comment: Hmmm... If all you need to do is show him your runtime, then dont worry - java generics stay only on compilation level, in .class file argument T1 key and T2 value are de facto Objects, its just hint for compiler to know what to expect of them. Anyway, I get it, teachers sometimes tend to stop you from selfimprovement fot the whole groups sake (I don't think that's right, but I understand that it happens).

Comment: I'd argue if in 100%, but it is wrong. Problem lies in the whole system - when there's one teacher for too many students, he has to constraint them a little, even if that means that they'll learn less, but at least most of them will learn enough. If there'd be one teacher for 3 people, he would have time to carry about each student enough for them to go ahead with syllabus. Anyway, that's my opinion and shouldn't be posted here on SO, it's not the place for that ;)